# Google Maps v2 div inside or over map

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, google-maps

I just need put one div (or more) inside or over map, something like a menu inside the map area,

I need when i load my map this div is there...

css can't do it right?

that div contains php code...

Comment: Do you want your menu div to disappear once the map is launched? Or do you want it to stay floating over the map?

Comment: i need div floating over,

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that can easily be done with CSS positioning. Consider the following short example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
  <title>Google Maps v2 API: Floating Div</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false"
          type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head> 
<body onunload="GUnload()"> 

  <div style="position: relative;">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div> 
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; 
                width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: grey;">
      Menu Here
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(38.00, -100.00), 3);
  </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot:

[image: Google Maps v2 API: Floating Div]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Google Maps API3.

Where my menu drop-down elements now overlays Google Maps API3 in the correct order.

This is the important css code:

```css
.menudropdown {
  position: fixed;
  z-index:2;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
}
```