# how to add html form over google maps?

Tags: google-maps, html

Can I add html form directly over the div that displays Google maps ?

Comment: You might need to be a bit more specific with your question to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, & Scott is right, you are better off being more specific - just a map and a html form (or any other kind of html element for that matter)?  Then of course yes.  Just some basic CSS will sort you out.

Even better would be to show us your code and someone will point out where it is going wrong if you're having trouble.  Try this [search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1210&bih=931&q=textbox+googlemap&btnG=Google+Search#sclient=psy&hl=en&biw=1210&bih=931&q=css+absolute+position+input+box+google+map&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=1&cad=b) if you need to begin somewhere.  Or even better your question is likely already answered here -> [Google Maps v2 div inside or over map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225170/google-maps-v2-div-inside-or-over-map).

One (slightly advanced) note though - it has been known to go funky when using FF2, but any other browser seems to have no problems.  References: [Infamous Firefox cursor bug](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?1519-Infamous-Firefox-cursor-bug-Info-and-possible-workarounds) & [Bug 167801](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=167801)